# Nestjs ClassSerializerInterceptor doesn't display _id

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I have an issue properly exposing the _id using the Serializer.

I use:

```js
@UseInterceptors(ClassSerializerInterceptor)
@SerializeOptions({ strategy: 'excludeAll' })
```

The defined Class:

```js
export class UpdatedCounts {
    @Expose()
    _id: ObjectId;
    @Expose()
    aCount: number;
    @Expose()
    bCount: number;

    constructor(partial: Partial<MyDocument>) {
        Object.assign(this, partial);
    }
}
```

The object in console.log() before it runs through the Serializer

```js
{
  _id: new ObjectId("61c2256ee0385774cc85a963"),
  bannerImage: 'placeholder2',
  previewImage: 'placeholder',
  aCount: 1,
  bCount: 0,
}
```

The object being returned:

```js
{
  "_id": {},
  "aCount": 1,
  "bCount": 0
}
```

So what happened to my _id?

I tried using string type instead of ObjectId but that also does not work

I do not want to use @Exclude since there are 10 more props which I left out in the example console.log(), and it should be easier to exclude all and just use these 3

Comment: try using `@Type(() => ObjectId)` on `_id` field

Comment: @MicaelLevi I had another person tell me the same thing, but unfortunately that does not work, idk if I am doing it wrong =,=

Comment: I can't tell. I've never tried using the builtin serializer, tbh. I'm using https://automapperts.netlify.app instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use [`@Transform`](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer/blob/develop/src/decorators/transform.decorator.ts):

```js
@Expose()
@Transform((params) => params.obj._id.toString())
_id: ObjectId;
```

You can not just send ObjectId with JSON. You must convert it to a string.

Comment: Ah yes this worked, thank you very much, I failed before seeing that I have to use the "obj"